# weird effect on jquery I fadeout

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm trying to show a `div` when a `li` is clicked and to hide it when other `li` is clicked. The problem is that a weird effect appears when I click on of the last `li`'s.

Here is how my code looks: http://jsfiddle.net/zxGqV/4/

I'm new in jQuery, so I'm sure that some of my code logic doesn't make sense.

```
$('.btn').click(function(c){
      c.preventDefault();
      var a = $(this).attr("id").replace('title_', '');
      $(this).closest("#elements").find('.btn').removeClass("current");
      $(this).closest('li').addClass("current");
      $("#elements").find('.details').fadeOut("slow", function(){
          $('.btn-group').find('#details_' + a).fadeIn("fast");
      });
});


<div class="row">
 <div class="span8 center">
  <ul id="elements" class="ui-sortable">

   <li id="element_10" class="">
     <div class="btn-group">
       <button id="title_10" type="button" class="btn">
         lorem 10</button>
       <div style="display: none;" id="details_10" class="details">
         lorem ipsum 10
       </div>               
     </div>
   </li>

   <li id="element_11" class="">
      <div class="btn-group">
       <button id="title_11" type="button" class="btn">
            foo 11</button>
       <div style="display: none;" id="details_11" class="details">
            foo bar 11
       </div>               
      </div>
   </li>
```

... etc

Comment: The fiddle you are linking to is empty. Also it would be great if you could post the relevant parts of your code here, so people whould could answer your question but don't want to click through may have a look at it.

Comment: theres nothing at your jsfiddle, just a css import

Comment: Your fiddle is empty.

Comment: @m90: sorry guys. jsfiddle link fixed

Comment: ok, what is the "weird" effect?

Comment: @Hogan: please check how the div appears when you click on the last divs. On fiddle you can see it.

Comment: @doledoug - yes, I see it.  I don't know what you want it to look like so I don't know how it is wrong.

Comment: @Hogan: i need that `details` div class to appear, not to appear/dissapear/appear/dissapear/appear on a single click.

Comment: @doledoug - ok, then you need to change the logic of your code to ignore the one associated with the current click.  All of your selectors select everything.  This is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works -- might want to adjust the timing.

Here I use current class to make sure I'm only working on one item at a time.

http://jsfiddle.net/cewFL/

```
$('.btn').click(function(c){
      c.preventDefault();
      $(this).attr("id").replace('title_', '');
      $(".current .details").fadeOut("fast");
      $(".current").removeClass("current");
      $(this).closest('li').addClass("current");
      $(".current .details").fadeIn("fast");

});
```

Comment: I like your approach. it is more cleaner. ty soo much!